# Rails: Secret Token Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I am using Rails 3.2.13 and get the following message:

```
ArgumentError (A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb):
```

I've found reference to this in [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/862389c9537dbb6f65fd26c4325e07607ed437b5) and a discussion [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4652).

I am using Devise (hence, Warden) and the info in the discussion is relevant. I'd prefer not to hack on the railtie gem -- what is the recommended action here?

Thanks

Stack trace:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Started GET "/" for 76.176.151.243 at 2013-07-20 12:34:25 -0700

ArgumentError (A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:319:in `ensure_secret_secure'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:284:in `initialize'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:231:in `new'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:231:in `signed'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:50:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:57:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:48:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:107:in `extract_session_id'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `block in extract_session_id'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:57:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `extract_session_id'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:43:in `load_session_id!'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:32:in `[]'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:267:in `current_session_id'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:273:in `session_exists?'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:107:in `exists?'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:127:in `load_for_read!'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:64:in `has_key?'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:258:in `ensure in call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:259:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1076913542946280817__call__830910935667466127__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  passenger (4.0.8) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.8) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.8) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.8) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` I have following

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!
# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
Friendflat::Application.config.secret_token = 'asdf...'
```

You should add the same, setting value to some long random hex string.

Comment: I have the same thing (different string). I don't think this is it.

Comment: @SteveRoss did you restart the server? can you add full trace? Is the name of the app (Friendflat here) a valid name?

Comment: Yes, I tried touching `tmp/restart.txt` and same results, then did an `apachectl restart` to make absolutely sure but got the same results. I've amended the original question to include the stack trace.